# Need Help with Flow for SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a simple workflow with a condition and it will not work.  I always get the email generated from 'yes" but if the company name "IS NOT" equal to the variable it should send out a different email.  What am i doing wrong?  Thank you!

[image: image of my flow]